# Antivirus removes Win32 project exe

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, antivirus

When I compile my Win32 Windows Application my antivirus thinks it is a virus and removes exe file, I have to turn off antivirus every time to compile project.
How can I solve this problem?
I think this is in the description, and I have to set manufacturer name.

Comment: you can solve it by turning off antivirus every time you compile project

Comment: and this is a solution??

Comment: yes, probably, since its not antivirus you wrote

Comment: So why antivirus not removes another Win32 applications?? There is a something that you can add into your project

Comment: It would help to know 1. which OS version are you on? and 2. which antivirus are you running?

Comment: Avast is a well-known troublemaker.  It seems especially sensitive to an EXE suddenly appearing from nowhere.  Best to just get rid of it.

Comment: We always add our project/build directories to the AV exclusion list. Otherwise the AV will slow down your builds as it goes scanning binaries, object files, etc.

Comment: And how middle level manufacturers avoids this antivirus problem?? There are a lot of not much big win32 programs which accepted by antivirus, I don't think all those programs was added to exclusion lists of all antiviruses:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various patterns in programs that let it be recognized by a scanner as a malware. This is heuristic scanning: the scanner doesn't recognize your program, but things it tries to do: API calls, certain ways or areas of memory or filesystem access, and so on.

Classic examples consist of reading Outlook's address book and trying to read or execute certain file paths.

> I think this is in the description, and I have to set manufacturer name.

So, what happens if you *don't* set the description (what is "the description" by the way)? Does the executable then *not* get deleted? There's your answer.

Anyway **you** will have to analyze why and when the virus scanner removes your executable. Compile your program partially, leaving out significant parts can help deduct which part is causing trouble, and reading the source might just point out why.

Comment: If I just create Win32 Project in Visual Studio 2012. that have some generated code and run it without changing any code antivirus immediately removes it:)

Comment: Then I highly suggest you start looking at that _"some generated code"_.

Comment: There is nothing dangerous, it's just simple win32 api calls, CreateWindow(), SendMEssage() etc.:))

Comment: @CodeCaster: +1 for mentioning heuristics, tho' I would be tempted to put your last line in `<sarcasm>` tags. Besides, you should probably define it on the compile command for the project: `/DNOT_A_VIRUS` :)

Comment: @CodeCaster Have you looked into the generated Win32 application template? There **really** is nothing dangerous in it. It registers a window class, creates a window and starts its message loop. It's a bare bones GUI application. The virus scanner in question certainly does not remove it based on what it does. In fact, the application does not even start, but gets deleted before the debugger even gets a chance to launch it.

Comment: You will have to contact the antivirus vendor to ask them why they think your program is malicious. We're just guessing.

Comment: @IInspectable it's unclear whether OP's virus scanner is deleting the executable resulting from just compiling the empty Win32 application template, or that OP is talking about _"some generated code"_ that's coming from somewhere else. Also, heuristic scanning doesn't require _the user_ to run the program. I don't like question and answer games, we've given OP a few hints and it's up to them to resolve this issue - edit: based on Hans' comment I found [Stop avast! from attacking my own programs](http://superuser.com/questions/555905/stop-avast-from-attacking-my-own-programs), perhaps relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Just an anecdote:

Few years ago I was playing with [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/). When I compiled one of the example programs, a simple Win32 program with a window, my antivirus removed the exe. It turned out that it was enough to change the name of the window class to solve the problem. (I don't know whether the *current* version of that TCC sample code is detected as a virus or not.)

Maybe your case can also be solved with a similar small change, without turning off the antivirus. Good luck :)

Comment: If I just create Win32 Project in Visual Studio 2012. that have some generated code and run it without changing any code antivirus immediately removes it:)]